# Событие при нажатии Enter

Tags: java, android

Есть TextView и при нажатии клавиши Enter курсор переходит на новую строку но в начало линии добавляется номер строки с точкой и пробелом. И все хорошо, кроме того, что добавляется еще один перенос строки уже после номера и фокус соответственно проваливается ниже. Не пойму в какой момент это происходит

```
mWorkEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                String string = mWorkEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!singleTypeMode)
                {
                    mWorkEditText.setText("");
                    string = string + "\n" + (lineCounter + 1) + ". ";
                    mWorkEditText.setText(string);
                    mWorkEditText.setSelection(string.length());
                    lineCounter++;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

получается вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно поставить брейкпойнт и пошагово смотреть, что происходит.

Comment: пробовал так пробежаться. Мой блок отрабатывает нормально и до return доходит строка "1. '\n'2. " (без одинарных кавычек)

Comment: А если в конце Вашей правки вернуть `return true`?

Comment: Сработало. Большое спасибо, надо значит покопать в сторону этого значения возвращаемого

Comment: Всё просто - `true` означает, что событие обработано здесь и больше действий не требуется.